# CSS not overriding presentational SVG attributes

Tags: css, svg, fill

I have an SVG shape as part of my SVG sprite:

```
<symbol id="flickr-logo" viewBox="-41.5 532.5 200 91.626">
    <circle fill="#0063DB" cx="4.313" cy="578.312" r="45.813" class="left" ></circle>
    <circle fill="#FF0084" cx="112.687" cy="578.312" r="45.813" class="right"></circle>
</symbol>
```

Now when I use `<svg ..><use ...></use></svg>` etc to include the actual shape on my page it works nicely and the fills inside the SVG circles show up fine.

Now, when I add my css from below:

```
.left {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.right {
   fill: #ffffff;
}
```

Nothing happens. I see the style is applying but the `fill="???"` presentational attribute on on the circle elements seem to be overriding. Is there a way to get the CSS to win out?

If I remove the `fill="????"` attribute then the css styles work perfectly but I need to keep them in.

I thought about editing the colours in the SVG but I can't as I need to display this shape in two locations. One in it's default colours and once in another place where I need to change the fills to white.

Any thoughts about how to do this?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Did you try !important ?

Comment: @BlagoEreš Yes, No such luck. No difference whatsoever.

Comment: http://slides.com/sarasoueidan/styling-animating-svgs-with-css#/16
Look at these slides. There is diagram that shows order of precedence.

Comment: So looking at that, my styles should be working or am I reading that incorrectly?

Comment: The class should be applied to the `use` element...not the sub-element inside the symbol. CSS can't "reach inside" SVG sub-elements unless they are inline.

Comment: @Paulie_D  Why? If I do that then I cannot target the correct circle instances.

Comment: That's the way it works with `use`...either you set the styles and live with them or you set no styles and use a class on the `use` that affects **all** internal parts.

Comment: @Paulie_D Not according to a lot of places. Look at this post: https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/ and specifically the part titled: "Yay: you can style them (and their parts) with CSS"

Comment: I think Chris meant like this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Jbjkw and if you check the example he gives he's not styling parts of the `use` just parts of the overall SVG each part of which has it's own definition. But I'll take another look if you can make a demo.

Comment: Ok, Take a look at this pen: http://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/myQVeE   If you have fill attributes on the paths then they seem to override the css applied styles. That's what I need to overcome.

Comment: If you don't want those colors to apply...don't use them...but if you don't use them then whatever fill style you apply in CSS will apply to all of the `use`. CSS cannot select **inside** a `use` to a particular sub-element (at least as far as I know). That's why for multicolored icons that you need to affect you have to build them out of multiple `use` elements. I'm still learning but that seems to be the way of it...if you find an alternative, I'll be happy.

Comment: @Paulie_D  Look at this pen then: http://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/bNQEEr   One use line and uses classes to style multiple parts.  Can we get back to solving the issue of how to get CSS styles to override the fill attributes?

Comment: By me, your code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6yxzydr1/1/ - the left and right classes override the svg fill color

Comment: @Danield Hmm, so it does. I'll have to take another look at mine. Thanks.

Comment: @Danield  Ok, So i've edited your test case here: http://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/QwJyNQ    Is this one not working due to the fact I ahve scoped the styles inside of .flickr ?

Comment: @rctneil, yes, you're right, I also just found this out in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/6yxzydr1/3/

Comment: @Danield hmm. It must be as it's just referencing the symbol.  So. How do I target a specific instance of the shape?   If I need two on a page in differing colours then there must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you remove the fill then CSS can be applied and work as expected.

You say you can't do this as you use the SVG in two places.
However your mark-up shows

```
<symbol id="flickr-logo" viewBox="-41.5 532.5 200 91.626">
```

So I guess that, you must be using another ID somewhere else (or you could use another ID somewhere else) such as id="flickr-logo-alt" as all the ID's on the page actually really need to unique.

You can then apply two little bits CSS to style both versions.

```
#flickr-logo .left {
  fill: #0063DB;
}
#flickr-logo .right {
   fill: #FF0084;
}
#flickr-logo-alt .left {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
#flickr-logo-alt .right {
   fill: #ffffff;
}
```

If you have other styling that references the ID and you don't have two on the page at the same time, then you could add a class to the symbol for the alternate case "alt" use different classes like this. The class can be applied directly or through scripting.

```
<symbol class="alt" id="flickr-logo" viewBox="-41.5 532.5 200 91.626">

#flickr-logo .left {
  fill: #0063DB;
}
#flickr-logo .right {
   fill: #FF0084;
}
#flickr-logo.alt .left {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
#flickr-logo.alt .right {
   fill: #ffffff;
}
```

or just apply an additional class to the left and right that already exist in the alt case. Which can be applied directly or though scripting.

```
<circle cx="4.313" cy="578.312" r="45.813" class="left alt" ></circle>
<circle cx="112.687" cy="578.312" r="45.813" class="right alt"></circle>

.left {
  fill: #0063DB;
}
.right {
   fill: #FF0084;
}
.left.alt {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
.right.alt {
   fill: #ffffff;
}
```